# A metric space embedded into a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a metric space but not a Hilbert space, is it possible that it can be isometrically embedded into a Hilbert space? Can anyone give an example?

Comment: I don't think so (for an arbitrary metric space) or else the wiki on Kuratowski embedding would say Hilbert space instead of Banach

Answer (score 2):

Embed a circle in $R^2$ by the inclusion map.

Comment: Under what metric?

Comment: the usual R2 metric